# Is this implementation of greedy Nqueens correct?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am using this resource: https://sites.google.com/site/nqueensolver/home/algorithms/3systematic-greedy-algorithm to implement a greedy Nqueens. One thing I didn't understand is when he wrote:

"In my version all the queens are placed in the same row / column and if the algorithm fails to find a solution the queens are moved to the next row / column. The queens can also placed randomly but no more than one queen may occupie a line. If there are no remaining rows / columns stop."

It sounds like he is only initializing N times, once for each column. But that doesn't make sense, since he is also using an outer infinite loop.

Here is my implementation:

```
Public NQueensSolver {
    public int[] nqueensgreedy ( int N ) {
        int[] result = new int[N]
        
        while (true) {
            int[] cols = new boolean[2 * N - 1];
            int[] diags = new boolean[2*N - 1];
            int[] revs = new boolean[2 * N - 1];

            for ( int row = 0 ; row < N; row++) {
                result[row] = Math.random(0,N)
                int col = result[row]
                mark(row, col, cols, diags, revs);
            }
            

            int iteration = 0;
            while (iteration++ < 15) {
                int total_attacks = 0;
                for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
                    int min_index = 0;
                    int min_val = 0;
                    unmark(row, result[row], cols, diags, revs)
                    for (int col  = 0; col < N; col++) {
                        int attacks = getAttacks(row, col, cols, diags,                                                 revs)
                        if ( attacks < min_val ) {
                            min_val = attacks
                            min_index = col
                        }
                    }
                    result[row] = min_index
                    total_attacks += min_value
                    mark(row, col, cols, diags, revs)
                }
                
                if (total_attacks = 0) return result;
            }
        }
        
        
        throw Exception(“No solution”)
        
    }

    private int getAttacks ( int row, int col, int[] cols, int[] diags, int[] revs )
        return cols[col] + diags[row+col] + revs[col-row + N - 1];

    private mark(int row, int col, int[] cols, int[] diags, int[] revs)
        cols[col] += 1;
        diags[row + col] += 1
        revs[col - row + N - 1] += 1

    private unmark(int row, int col, int[] cols, int[] diags, int[] revs)
        cols[col] -= 1;
        diags[row + col] -= 1
        revs[col - row + N - 1] -= 1

}
```

Edit: I fixed the mistakes noted in the comments (thank you). Please ignore any missing semi-colons or curly braces. I trust that you can understand via indents and newlines. This is more pseudocode even though it is closest syntactically to java.
I hope that future feedback is more related to the conceptual question referenced in the link rather than comments about syntax.

Thank you.

Comment: There appear to be several syntax errors (missing semicolons, mismatched parentheses) in the section with: `result[row] = min_index`

Comment: This code makes no sense. There is a reference to an undefined variable `col` in the first `unmark` call. There is an incomplete `if` condition at `if ( min_val < {`.  Semi-colons are missing. Curly quotes are wrong. I stopped looking further at this point. Moving on.

Comment: Please understand my comment was about your code, not about you. No need to start being personal.

Comment: @trincot I apologize. I didn't mean to be rude as well. I appreciate your time spent to comment, and edited my post accordingly. Have a nice day.